# Difficulty understanding the ggplotly interface for custom geoms

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

I've had some success [extending `ggflags` to use SVGs](https://github.com/rensa/ggflags), and now I'm trying to make this extension play nice with `ggplotly()`. The Plotly documentation [has a nice section on translating custom geoms](https://plotly-book.cpsievert.me/translating-custom-ggplot2-geoms.html), and it essentially comes down to either providing a `to_basic` method for your geom or a `geom2trace` method.

I'm gonna be honest: I'm outta my depth here, and I'm trying to cobble something together based on the two named examples: [`ggmosaic`](https://github.com/haleyjeppson/ggmosaic/blob/master/R/geom2plotly.R) and [`ggalt`](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/ggalt/blob/master/R/geom2plotly.r). But something simple like:

```
#' @name plotly_helpers
#' @title Plotly helpers
#' @description Helper functions to make it easier to automatically create plotly charts
#' @importFrom plotly to_basic
#' @export
to_basic.GeomFlag <- getFromNamespace("to_basic.GeomPoint", asNamespace("plotly"))
```

Gives me an error when running `devtools::document()`:

```
object 'to_basic.GeomPoint' not found
```

if I change it to GeomLine the package documents and installs, but a simple plot displays like this:

```
df = data_frame(
    f = rep(1:5, each = 4),
    x = rep(1:4, times = 5),
    y = c(1:2, 2:1, 2:1, 1:2, 1:2, 2:1, 2:1, 1:2, 2:1, 1:2),
    s = c(1:4, 4:1, 1:4, 4:1, 1:4),
    c = rep(c('au', 'us', 'gb', 'de'), 5))

p1 = ggplot(df) + geom_flag(aes(x = x, y = y, size = s, frame = f, country = c)) + scale_country()
ggplotly(p1)
```

[image]

Obviously GeomLine isn't right—GeomPoint seems like a more natural point for this extension—but it could simply be that I can't reduce it and I need to implement `geom2trace`. But I don't really have a great idea of what needs to go in or out of either method. Can anyone help? Are there other examples of `ggplot2` extensions that implement the Plotly interfaces?

**EDIT:** I've had a look at [some of the built-in examples of `geom2trace`](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/blob/master/R/layers2traces.R#L593), but I'm not sure I can go much further here. I was kind of hoping I might be able to substitute custom grobs for the GeomPoint points, like with `grid`, but it seems like the Plotly API expects just basic point attributes.

Comment: Hi @rensa, did you ever figure this out? I'm trying to do essentially the same thing.

Comment: Unfortunately not, @bmac; I sought some help on the plotly forums, but it looks like custom geoms really need to be at least composed of the traces plotly provides.

Comment: In the end I decided to export an SVG from ggplot2 using grid2SVG and animate it myself with jQuery (or d3, or whatever else). I discuss an example of that technique [here](https://medium.com/@rensa/challenges-visualising-climate-extremes-with-leaflet-7a407162d75f#b559), and I'm working on some other examples that I'll write up soon :)

Comment: Ok thanks for following up @rensa, I'll check out that link!